# android - cannot to get CurrentLocation

Tags: android, maps

I'm trying to get my current location to stablish the initial point for a user's path. The code is running but the GoogleApiClient won't connect.

I don't know what am I doing wrong. Any help will be most appreciated.

Thanks

```
package com.csusbCampusTracking;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener;

import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.InfoWindowAdapter;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener;


import com.google.android.gms.maps.CameraUpdateFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.BitmapDescriptorFactory;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLngBounds;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;


import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.SystemClock;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.location.Location;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;

import android.text.SpannableString;
import android.text.style.ForegroundColorSpan;

import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener;
import android.view.animation.BounceInterpolator;
import android.view.animation.Interpolator;

import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

/**
 * An activity that creates a map with some initial options.
 */
public class displayMap extends FragmentActivity implements
OnMarkerClickListener,
OnInfoWindowClickListener,
ConnectionCallbacks,
OnConnectionFailedListener,
LocationListener

{
  public double latitud;
  public double longitud; 
  public LatLng ORIGIN; // = new LatLng(34.02143074239393, -117.61349469423294);
  public LatLng DESTINY; 
  private GoogleMap mMap;
  private Marker mDestiny;
  private Marker mOrigin;
  private Marker mLastSelectedMarker; // keeps track of last selected marker

  private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;

  // These settings are the same as the settings for the map. They will in fact provide updates
  // at the maximal rates currently possible.
  private static final LocationRequest REQUEST = LocationRequest.create()
    .setInterval(5000)         // 5 seconds
    .setFastestInterval(16)    // 16ms = 60fps
    .setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);


  /***************************
   * On CREATE method        *
   ***************************/
  @Override
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.map);

    setUpGoogleApiClientIfNeeded();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() ){
      System.out.println("Conected *****");
    }else {
      System.out.println("Not conected *****"); 
    }
    if (mLastSelectedMarker != null && mLastSelectedMarker.isInfoWindowShown()) {
      // Refresh the info window when the info window's content has changed.
      mLastSelectedMarker.showInfoWindow();
    }
    setUpMapIfNeeded();
  }

  /********************************
   * setUpGoogleApiClientIfNeeded *
   * ******************************/
  private void setUpGoogleApiClientIfNeeded() {
    if (mGoogleApiClient == null) {
      mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
        .addApi(LocationServices.API)
        .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
        .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
        .build();
    }
  }

  /********************************
   * setUpMapIfNeeded             *
   * ******************************/
  private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
    // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
    if (mMap == null) {
      // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
      mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
        .getMap();
        // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
        if (mMap != null) {
          mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
          setUpMap();
        }
    }
  }

  /********************************
   * setUpMap                     *
   * ******************************/
  private void setUpMap() {

    double longitude = getLong(); // target 
    double latitude =  getLat();  // info.

    getLocation(ORIGIN);
    ORIGIN = new LatLng(34.02143074239393, -117.61349469423294);
    DESTINY = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    // Hide the zoom controls as the button panel will cover it.
    mMap.getUiSettings().setZoomControlsEnabled(false);
    addMarkersToMap();

    // customizing the info window.
    mMap.setInfoWindowAdapter(new CustomInfoWindowAdapter());

    // Set listeners for marker events.  
    mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this); // to display infowindow
    mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(this); // to display extra info

    // Pan to see all markers in view.
    // Cannot zoom to bounds until the map has a size.
    final View mapView = getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map).getView();
    if (mapView.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive()) {
      mapView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation") // We use the new method when supported
        @SuppressLint("NewApi") // We check which build version we are using.
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
          LatLngBounds bounds = new LatLngBounds.Builder() // defines the map bounds 
          .include(DESTINY)
          .include(ORIGIN)
          .build();
          if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.JELLY_BEAN) {
            mapView.getViewTreeObserver().removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);
          } else {
            mapView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
          }
          mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(bounds, 50));
        }
      });
    }
  } // end setUpMap


  /*************************************************
   *                ORIGIN2                        *                       
   * Retrieves current latitude and longitude      *
   *************************************************/
  public LatLng getLocation(LatLng ORIGIN2) {

    setUpGoogleApiClientIfNeeded();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    if (mGoogleApiClient.isConnected() ){
      System.out.println("Conected 8888");
    }else {
      System.out.println("Not Conected 8888"); 
    }

    if (mGoogleApiClient != null && mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
      String msg = "Location = "
      + LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.getLastLocation(mGoogleApiClient);
      System.out.println("We are mGoogleApiClient ");
      Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    } else { 
      System.out.println("We are not mGoogleApiClient ");
    }
    return ORIGIN2; 
  }


  /*********************************************************
   * Implementation of {@link OnConnectionFailedListener}. *
   *********************************************************/
  @Override
  public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
      // Do nothing
  }


  /*************************************
   *               addMarker           *
   *************************************/
  private void addMarkersToMap() {
    // initial position marker
    String targetTitle = getTargetTitle();
    mOrigin = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(ORIGIN)
    .title("Origin")
    .snippet("Point of Start")
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_AZURE)));

    double latitude = getLat();
    double longitude = getLong(); 

    DESTINY = new LatLng(latitude, longitude);
    // target position marker
    mDestiny = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
    .position(DESTINY)
    .title("Destiny")
    .snippet(targetTitle) 
    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.arrow))); 
  }

  /*************************************
   *           checkReady              *
   *************************************/
  private boolean checkReady() {
    if (mMap == null) {
      Toast.makeText(this, R.string.map_not_ready, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      return false;
    }
    return true;
  }

  /*************************************
   *           onToggleFlat            *
   *************************************/
  public void onToggleFlat(View view) {
    if (!checkReady()) {
      return;
    }
  }

  /*************************************
   *           onResume                *
   *************************************/
  @Override
  protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
    setUpGoogleApiClientIfNeeded();
    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
   setUpMapIfNeeded();
  }

  /*************************************
   *           onPause                 *
   *************************************/
  @Override
  public void onPause() {
      super.onPause();
      if (mGoogleApiClient != null) {
          mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
      }
  }

  /*******************************
   * Callback (generated)        *
   *******************************/
  @Override
  public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
    mGoogleApiClient, REQUEST, (LocationListener) this);  // LocationListener
  }


  /*************************************
   *           onMarkerClick           *
   *************************************/  @Override
  public boolean onMarkerClick(final Marker marker) {
    if (marker.equals(mDestiny)) {
      // This causes the marker at target to bounce into position when it is clicked.
      final Handler handler = new Handler();
      final long start = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
      final long duration = 1500;
      final Interpolator interpolator = new BounceInterpolator();

      handler.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
          long elapsed = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - start;
          float t = Math.max(1 - interpolator.getInterpolation((float) elapsed / duration), 0);
          marker.setAnchor(0.5f, 1.0f + 2 * t);
          if (t > 0.0) {
            // Post again 16ms later.
            handler.postDelayed(this, 16);
          }
        }
      });
    }  

    mLastSelectedMarker = marker;
    // We return false to indicate that we have not consumed the event and that we wish
    // for the default behavior to occur (which is for the camera to move such that the
    // marker is centered and for the marker's info window to open, if it has one).
    return false;
  }


   /*************************************
    *       onInfoWindowClick           *
    *************************************/
   @Override
  public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker marker) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Click Info Window", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
  }


   /*************************************
    *       MyLocationListener          *
    *************************************/
  public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {
    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
      loc.getLatitude();
      loc.getLongitude();
    }

    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
  }

  /****************************************
   * This defines the marker's info       *
   * two view texts and a snippet         *
   ****************************************/

  private void render(Marker marker, View view) {
    int badge;
    // It won't work with ==> == Must use==> equals()  
    if ( marker.equals(mOrigin) | marker.equals(mDestiny) ) {
      badge = R.drawable.badge_csusb;
    } else {
      // Passing 0 to setImageResource will clear the image view.
      badge = 0;
    }
    ((ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.badge)).setImageResource(badge);
    String title = marker.getTitle();
    TextView titleUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.title));
    if (title != null) {
      // SpannableString allows to edit the formatting of the text.
      SpannableString titleText = new SpannableString(title);
      titleText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.RED), 0, titleText.length(), 0);
      titleUi.setText(titleText);
    } else {
      titleUi.setText("");
    }

    String snippet = marker.getSnippet();
    TextView snippetUi = ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.snippet));
    if (snippet != null && snippet.length() > 12) {
      SpannableString snippetText = new SpannableString(snippet);
      snippetText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 0, 12, 0);
      snippetText.setSpan(new ForegroundColorSpan(Color.BLUE), 12, snippet.length(), 0);
      snippetUi.setText(snippetText);
    } else {
      snippetUi.setText("");
    }
  } // end of marker info


  class CustomInfoWindowAdapter implements InfoWindowAdapter {
    private final View mWindow;
    CustomInfoWindowAdapter() {
      mWindow = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.custom_info_window, null);
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoWindow(Marker marker) {
      render(marker, mWindow);
      return mWindow;
    }

    @Override
    public View getInfoContents(Marker arg0) {
      // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      return null;
    }
  }  // end of CustomInfoWindowAdapter


  public double getLat() {
    Intent i= getIntent();
    double latitude   = i.getExtras().getDouble("locLat");
    return latitude; 
  }

  public double getLong () {
    Intent i= getIntent();
    double longitude = i.getExtras().getDouble("locLong");
    return longitude;
  }

  public String getTargetTitle () {
    Intent i= getIntent();
    String targetTitle = i.getExtras().getString("locDesc");
    return targetTitle;
  }


  public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }


  public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }


  public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }


  public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }


  @Override
  public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  }

}// end of program
// Java Document
```

Comment: Any error from LogCat?

Comment: No errors, it's just that it will not connect. It'll print the message "not connected" that I'm using as a flag to trace the program

Comment: I'm trying to emulate a GPS with this program, by now I just have to the point where I can select the target destiny coordinates. I am forcing the source coordinates as: ORIGIN = new LatLng(34.02143074239393, -117.61349469423294);  When I comment this line the program fails, and the catlog is as follows:

Comment: 01-27 09:53:30.265: E/AndroidRuntime(10946): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-27 09:53:30.265: E/AndroidRuntime(10946): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.csusbCampusTracking/com.csusbCampusTracking.displayMap}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: no position in marker options
01-27 09:53:30.265: E/AndroidRuntime(10946):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1658)
01-27 09:53:30.265: E/AndroidRuntime(10946):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1674)

Answer (score 0):

I'll answer this one, just in case someone has the same problem, the code does work. However, if the device cannot get connected to the satellite, then it won't send any message of not being successful. In my case I happened to test the program outside my house and it worked.

Cheers